# Post not getting all my array variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where I ask for previous addresses.  I am using an array to collect the addresses.  It is setup to only show for one address and then they can click a button an another set of address fields will appear so they can enter as many as they like.  The idea is for them to enter their last 7 years of where they lived.  The issue I am getting is when the post comes through I am only getting the first set of addresses.  I am not sure what is wrong as I have done this before.

Here is the first set of address fields html

```
<div class='row address1'>
  <div class='addresstxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addresstxt' name='address[1][txt]' id='address1txt' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)" />
  </div>
  <div class='addresscitytxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addresscitytxt' name='address[1][city]' id='address1city' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)" />
  </div>
  <div class='addressstatetxt'>
    <select class='addressstatetxt' name='address[1][state]' id='address1state'>
      <option disabled selected value='select'>Select</option>
      Taken out to shorten
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class='addresscountytxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addresscountytxt' name='address[1][county]' id='address1county' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)" />
  </div>
  <div class='addressziptxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addressziptxt' name='address[1][zip]' id='address1zip' />
  </div>
  <div class='addressfromtxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start' name='address[1][from]' id='address1from' />
  </div>
  <div class='addresstilltxt'>
    <input type='text' class='addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start' name='address[1][till]' id='address1till' value='' />
  </div>
</div>
```

If someone clicks on add another address this is what will be appended right after the above html.

```
<div class="row address2">
  <div class="addresstxt">
    <input type="text" class="addresstxt" name="address[2][txt]" id="address2txt" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class="addresscitytxt">
    <input type="text" class="addresscitytxt" name="address[2][city]" id="address2city" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class="addressstatetxt">
    <select class="addressstatetxt" name="address[2][state]" id="address2state">

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="addresscountytxt">
    <input type="text" class="addresscountytxt" name="address[2][county]" id="address2county" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
  </div>
  <div class="addressziptxt">
    <input type="text" class="addressziptxt" name="address[2][zip]" id="address2zip">
  </div>
  <div class="addressfromtxt">
    <input type="text" class="addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][from]" id="address2from">
  </div>
  <div class="addresstilltxt">
    <input type="text" class="addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][till]" id="address2till" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="row address2">
    <div class="addresstxt">
      <input type="text" class="addresstxt" name="address[2][txt]" id="address2txt" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="addresscitytxt">
      <input type="text" class="addresscitytxt" name="address[2][city]" id="address2city" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="addressstatetxt">
      <select class="addressstatetxt" name="address[2][state]" id="address2state">

      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="addresscountytxt">
      <input type="text" class="addresscountytxt" name="address[2][county]" id="address2county" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)">
    </div>
    <div class="addressziptxt">
      <input type="text" class="addressziptxt" name="address[2][zip]" id="address2zip">
    </div>
    <div class="addressfromtxt">
      <input type="text" class="addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][from]" id="address2from">
    </div>
    <div class="addresstilltxt">
      <input type="text" class="addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][till]" id="address2till" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I do a var_dump of $_POST for the address I only get the first one entered.

```
  ["address"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["txt"]=>
      string(8) "123 Test"
      ["city"]=>
      string(4) "City"
      ["state"]=>
      string(6) "CANADA"
      ["county"]=>
      string(6) "County"
      ["zip"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
      ["from"]=>
      string(10) "02/01/2016"
      ["till"]=>
      string(10) "02/02/2016"
    }
  }
```

The only reason I can think of what might be the issue is because I am adding the set after the page is loaded by the click on the add address button but I am fairly sure I have added input fields on the fly before and it has not been an issue.  Hoping someone can jump in and maybe let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Are you submitting a `<form>` or are you using AJAX to send the info to the server? If a form, ensure that everything falls between the opening and closing form tags...

Comment: Submitting a form.  On that page I am just doing echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
exit; To see all of the form variables

Comment: I'm sure you've checked, but to save time just-in-case, you have all of the inputs between the `<form>` and `</form>` tags, right?

Comment: Yes.  Double and triple checked that.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? This sounds like a nesting problem, or do you do something before submitting?

Comment: First, there are two sets of address[2] details in your question for after the user clicks the buttons, I assume the second set should be address[3].
Second, in whatever JS event you use to detect the button press and append the data, what selector do you use to append the data? Something like $('.formclass').append(additionalData) should work, but if you print the additional inputs outside the form it won't appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version of what you provided, not sure what is different between your code. My assumption (though clouded by your comments) is that your JS event appends the additional inputs outside the `<form>`. If not, maybe having this working code can allow you to figure out what's wrong with yours. When I use `var_dump($_POST);` on the PHP backend (submit.php) I see all three address arrays.

```
<button class='new-addresses'>Click</button>
<form action='submit.php' method='post'>
  <div class='row address1'>
    <div class='addresstxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addresstxt' name='address[1][txt]' id='address1txt' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"/>
    </div>
    <div class='addresscitytxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addresscitytxt' name='address[1][city]' id='address1city' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"/>
    </div>
    <div class='addressstatetxt'>
      <select class='addressstatetxt' name='address[1][state]' id='address1state'>
        <option disabled selected value='select'>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='addresscountytxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addresscountytxt' name='address[1][county]' id='address1county' onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"/>
    </div>
    <div class='addressziptxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addressziptxt' name='address[1][zip]' id='address1zip'/>
    </div>
    <div class='addressfromtxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start' name='address[1][from]' id='address1from'/>
    </div>
    <div class='addresstilltxt'>
      <input type='text' class='addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start' name='address[1][till]' id='address1till' value=''/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
<script>
  $(".new-addresses").on('click', function(){
    $("form input[type=submit]").before(
    '<div class="row address2"><div class="addresstxt"><input type="text" class="addresstxt" name="address[2][txt]" id="address2txt" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addresscitytxt"><input type="text" class="addresscitytxt" name="address[2][city]" id="address2city" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addressstatetxt"><select class="addressstatetxt" name="address[2][state]" id="address2state"></select></div><div class="addresscountytxt"><input type="text" class="addresscountytxt" name="address[2][county]" id="address2county" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addressziptxt"><input type="text" class="addressziptxt" name="address[2][zip]" id="address2zip"></div><div class="addressfromtxt"><input type="text" class="addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][from]" id="address2from"></div><div class="addresstilltxt"><input type="text" class="addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[2][till]" id="address2till" value=""></div><div class="row address3"><div class="addresstxt"><input type="text" class="addresstxt" name="address[3][txt]" id="address3txt" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addresscitytxt"><input type="text" class="addresscitytxt" name="address[3][city]" id="address3city" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addressstatetxt"><select class="addressstatetxt" name="address[3][state]" id="address3state"></select></div><div class="addresscountytxt"><input type="text" class="addresscountytxt" name="address[3][county]" id="address3county" onchange="capwords(this.id, this.value)"></div><div class="addressziptxt"><input type="text" class="addressziptxt" name="address[3][zip]" id="address3zip"></div><div class="addressfromtxt"><input type="text" class="addressfromtxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[3][from]" id="address3from"></div><div class="addresstilltxt"><input type="text" class="addresstilltxt datepicker_recurring_start hasDatepicker" name="address[3][till]" id="address3till" value=""></div></div>'
    );
  });
</script>
```

Edit: Here's the PHP output (I didn't add options to the selects, so they don't show up on the PHP page):

```
array (size=1)
  'address' => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'txt' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'city' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'county' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'zip' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'from' => string 'test' (length=4)
          'till' => string 'test' (length=4)
      2 => 
        array (size=6)
          'txt' => string 'test2' (length=5)
          'city' => string 'test2' (length=5)
          'county' => string 'test2' (length=5)
          'zip' => string 'test2' (length=5)
          'from' => string 'test2' (length=5)
          'till' => string 'test2' (length=5)
      3 => 
        array (size=6)
          'txt' => string 'test3' (length=5)
          'city' => string 'test3' (length=5)
          'county' => string 'test3' (length=5)
          'zip' => string 'test3' (length=5)
          'from' => string 'test3' (length=5)
          'till' => string 'test3' (length=5)
```

Comment: This is working for me as well.  I am going to try to integrate this into my existing code.  I am thinking maybe something in my function to add the inputs could be the culprit.  Thanks